Existence of minimal bases in additive combinatorics
Let $\mathbb{N}$ denote the set of natural numbers, including zero. A subset $X \subseteq N$ is a basis if $X + X = \mathbb{N}$. Clearly, if $X$ is a basis and $X \subseteq Y$, then $Y$ is also a basis. A basis $X$ is said to be minimal, if for each strict subset $Y \subset X$, $Y$ is not a basis.
Is it true that for every basis $X$, there exists $Y\subseteq X$, such that $Y$ is a minimal basis?

Since the intersection of a descending chain of bases is a basis, this follows from Zorn's lemma (and there is an explicit choice function using lexicographic ordering so it is easy to check that the axiom of choice is not needed).

Thanks @WillSawin! If the descending chain is finite, then it seems clear that the intersection is a basis. However, would we get a basis even if the chain is infinite? This seems non-trivial.

It is trivial. For each $n\in \mathbb N$, there are only finitely many pairs $a,b\in \mathbb N$ with $a+b \in \mathbb N$, and an arbitrary descending chain of nonempty finite sets has nonempty intersection.

Indeed! Now I understand and it seems that this essentially follows from the fact that a finite subcollection of the chain has an upper bound.

From a nonminimal basis we can just greedily remove the smallest element that leaves it a basis.  Continue in the same fashion, and take the intersection of this chain.
